# Asset loader for a small game

Tags: javascript

I have made a small game just for my own practicing. While making it I wrote an asset loader, which (as the name says) loads assets. But my main knowledge and effort was on the game, so now I am wondering how I could improve the asset loader.

On the bright side: It does the job quite well, no matter what changes I put in.
On the down side: It is tailored to a specific file format which I half invented.

So any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
/*
    CPS (Continuation-passing Style) is used a lot here because it makes
the work with callbacks (and async functions) a lot more convienent, but
it needs some time to get your head around it.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style
*/

var gCachedData = [];
var gameLoop;

AssetLoader = {
    currentGame: null,

    downloaders: {
        // These are extentions assosiated with a method to download them.
        '.js': function(file, save, count){
            var c = function(response){
                save(file, response.currentTarget.responseText);
                count();
            }
            gUtil.xhrGet(file, c, 'text');
        },
        '.png': function(file, save, count){
            var c = function(res){
                var image = res.target;
                var x =  {
                    img: image,
                    def: {
                        frame: {x: 0, y: 0, w: image.width, h: image.height},
                        rotated: false
                    }
                };
                save(file, x);
                count();
            };

            var i = new Image();
            i.onload = c
            i.onerror = function(e){console.log(e)}
            i.src = file;
        },
        '-sprite.png': function(file, save, count){
            // This is a sprite, download it and 
            // download the corrosponding JSON file.
            var x = {
                img: null,
                def: null
            }

            var enterImagesFromSprite = function(x){
                for(var imageName in x.def.frames){
                    var xx = {
                        img: x.img,
                        def: x.def.frames[imageName]
                    }
                    save(imageName, xx);
                }
                count();
            }

            var cImage = function(res){
                x.img = res.target;
                if(x.def)
                    enterImagesFromSprite(x);
            };
            var cJSON = function(res){
                x.def = JSON.parse(res.currentTarget.responseText);
                if(x.img)
                    enterImagesFromSprite(x);
            }

            var i = new Image();
            i.onload = cImage;
            i.src = file;
            var dot = file.lastIndexOf('.');
            var jsonFile = file.substring(0, dot) + '.json';
            gUtil.xhrGet(jsonFile, cJSON, 'text');
        },
        '.wav': function(file, save, count){
            var c = function(response){
                var audio_context = null;
                try{
                    audio_context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
                }catch(e){
                    console.log('Not able to play sounds');
                }

                var x = {
                    buffer: null,
                    loaded: false
                };

                audio_context.decodeAudioData(
                    response.currentTarget.response,
                    function(buffer){
                        x.buffer = buffer;
                        x.loaded = true;
                        save(file, x);
                        count();
                    }
                );
            }
            gUtil.xhrGet(file, c, 'arraybuffer');
        },
        'default': function(file, cont){
            console.log('We have no handler for this file:', file);
            cont();
        }
    },

    loadListOfElements: function(list, callback){
        if((!list) || list.length == 0){
            callback();
            return;
        }

        var loader = {
            elementsLeft: list.length,
            cb: callback
        };

        function saveDataToCache(filename, object){
            if((filename != undefined) && (object != undefined))
                gCachedData[filename] = object;
        }

        function countAsset(){
            --loader.elementsLeft;
            if(loader.elementsLeft == 0)
                loader.cb();
        }

        for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
            file = list[i]
            var extension;
            if(file.endsWith('-sprite.png')){
                extension = '-sprite.png';
            }else{
                var dot = file.lastIndexOf('.');
                extension = file.substring(dot);
            }
            if(this.downloaders[extension]){
                this.downloaders[extension](file, saveDataToCache, countAsset);
            }else{
                console.log('We have no handler for this file:', file);
            }
        }
    },

    loadLevel: function(i){
        if(this.currentGame){
            this.unloadLevel();
        }

        // The following things should happen in that order:
        // 1. Load the code
        // 2. Eval the code (with inner order defined in the json file)
        // 3. Load assets.
        // 4. Start the game.

        var LoadTheLevel = function(filename, cont){
            var c = (function(filename, cont){
                return SaveTheFileString(filename, cont);
            })(filename, cont);
            gUtil.xhrGet(filename, c, 'text');
        }

        var SaveTheFileString = function(filename, cont){
            return function(res){
                gCachedData[filename] = res.currentTarget.responseText;
                ParseTheLevelString(gCachedData[filename], cont);
            }
        }.bind(this);

        var ParseTheLevelString = function(str, cont){
            LoadCode(gUtil.parseLevelData(str), cont);
        }

        var LoadCode = function(json, cont){
            var c = (function(cont, levelStruct){
                return function(res){
                    evalTheCode(levelStruct);
                    LoadAssets(levelStruct.assets, cont);
                }
            })
            this.loadListOfElements(json.code, c(cont, json));
        }.bind(this);

        var evalTheCode = function(levelStruct){
            // Eval by order.
            for(var i=0; i<levelStruct.code.length; i++){
                eval(gCachedData[levelStruct.code[i]]);
            }
        }

        var LoadAssets = function(list, cont){
            this.loadListOfElements(list, cont);
        }.bind(this);

        var StartTheGame = function(levelSting){
            var levelStruct = gUtil.parseLevelData(levelSting);
            this.currentGame = new GameEngineClass(levelStruct.world);
            this.currentGame.setup(levelStruct.entities, levelStruct.world.camera);
            canvas.focus();
            gameLoop = setInterval(this.currentGame.update.bind(this.currentGame), 13);
        }.bind(this);

        var fileName = i + '.json';
        if(!gCachedData[fileName]){
            LoadTheLevel(fileName, function(){StartTheGame(gCachedData[fileName]);});
        }else{
            StartTheGame(gCachedData[fileName]);
        }
    },

    unloadLevel: function(){
        // TODO: Remove assets or not?
        clearInterval(gameLoop);
        try{
            this.currentGame.prepareGameEnd();
        }catch(ignor){}
        gameLoop = null;
        document.getElementById('canvasDebug').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('reloadButton').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
};

var stop = AssetLoader.unloadLevel.bind(AssetLoader);   // Just a helper for debugging.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loading logic is aware of the sequence. `LoadTheLevel` is aware of `SaveTheFileString`, `SaveTheFileString` is aware of `ParseTheLevelString`, `ParseTheLevelString` is aware of `LoadCode` and so forth. If ever you need to add another operation in this pipeline, you will have to touch the code of two other operations. While it doesn't sound that bad, it will often times lead to a domino effect of having to reconstruct the entire sequence.

Consider using Promises instead. It's still the same continuation-style, but with more structure and decouples your API from the flow logic. All your component functions ever need to know is that it should return a promise that resolves with a value or rejects with an error. It won't be aware of the other functions nor the sequence of the operation.

```
function loadLevel(...){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){ ... });
}

function evaluateData(...){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){ ... });
}

function loadAssets(...){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){ ... });
}

function initializeGame(...){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){ ... });
}

// Dummy promise. I just use it to indent the entire sequence.
Promise.resolve()
  .then(function(){
    return loadLevel(...);
  })
  .then(function(levelData){
    // Do something with levelData

    return evaluateData(...);
  })
  .then(function(evaluatedData){
    // Do something with evaluatedData

    return loadAssets(...);
  })
  .then(function(loadedAssets){
    // Do something with loadedAssets

    return initializeGame(...);
  })
  .then(function(){
    // By now, everything is ready.
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    // Something went horribly wrong somewhere.
  });
```

Another issue is difficulty in reasoning about the code. Consider this snippet:

```
'.js': function(file, save, count){
    var c = function(response){
        save(file, response.currentTarget.responseText);
        count();
    }
    gUtil.xhrGet(file, c, 'text');
},
```

I understand that `file` is a url and `xhrGet` appears to be some sort of AJAX call using GET. But what is `save`? What is `count`? When is this `.js` function called? Where is it called in the code? This style of passing around control makes it hard to trace the flow of the code. You jump from that loop that loops through `list`, to this function, then you look for what `save` is, then go back to this function, then look for what `count` is. While it makes sense technically, it's hard to follow through.

Like above, I highly suggest you keep the flow and logic on the caller side of the operation. Leave the component functions unaware and independent of each other.

```
function selectedParser(item){
  ...
  return parsedData;
}

function selectedDownloader(itemData){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    ...
  });
}

function downloadedItemParser(item){
  ...
  return parsedData;
}

var downloadPromises = list.map(function(item){
  // parse the data needed from item, and return it for next operation.
  return selectedParser(item);
}).map(function(parsedData){
  // Determine the downloader, an call it. Have it return a promise.
  return selectedDownloader(parsedData);
});

// Wait for all promises to complete
Promise.all(downloadPromises)
  .then(function(downloadedItems){
    // downloadedItems is an array of responses from the requests
    // in the same order as downloadPromises.
    return downloadedItems.map(function(item){
      return downloadedItemParser(item);
    });
  })
  .then(function(parsedData){
    // we've got finished data. Use and/or cache.
  });
```

In this pseudo-code `selectedParser`, `selectedDownloader`, `downloadedItemParser` will not be aware of each other nor the order they're called. All they know is that they receive data, do something with it and return something. What the input to these functions and what is done to their output is determined by the flow logic that is above.